# PuLP - Is there a way to access the variable names from dict instead of parsing the string version from .variables()?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

I am using PuLP for Python to solve some linear programming problems. Currently the only way I was able to find, to retrieve the variable name after solving the model is to parse the string version of it's name available in the `pulp.LpProblem().variables()` method which lists all the variables used.
However, this returns a string along the lines of `sometext('var1','var2')`. So I need to parse the text to access the string name so that I can get it's correct `.varValue`.

Is there a way to access this variables in a dict-like manner or is parsing the string the only way?

Comment: I don't think you can, though you can create a dictionary out of them. `{v.name:v.varValue for v in model.variables()}`

Answer (score 3):

You can directly access the variables without having to retrieve them.
Consider the following example:

```
>>> import pulp
>>> x = pulp.LpVariable('x',0,3)
>>> y = pulp.LpVariable('y',0,3)
>>> prob = pulp.LpProblem('example',pulp.LpMinimize)
>>> prob+= x+y
>>> prob+= x+y >= 4
>>> prob.solve()
1           
>>> x.varValue
1.0
>>> y.varValue
3.0
```

The same holds for other variables containers such as dictionaries

```
>>> x_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('x', range(1,6), lowBound=0, upBound=1)
>>> x_vars
{1: x_1, 2: x_2, 3: x_3, 4: x_4, 5: x_5}
```

where using the key you can access the value of the associated variable, e.g., `x_vars[1].varValue`

Comment: Ok, I guess I see the way you'd go about it. In this case I have passed tuples for indexs which results in the name being some composite of the text in each element of the tuple which is a nightmare to fetch back after solving. Seems like would be better off having non-composite names for vars and doing the mapping outside.